# how can i make my buttons resize

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

Been having a right headache trying to get my buttons to resize with my window.
I've tried all sorts of things but to no avail, I've managed to get the buttons to move position when resized but just can't seem to bind the buttons to the screen, I just get errors.

I have narrowed my script down to just one function so its easier to read, if somebody could point me in the right direction I would be much obliged.

Thanks

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from Tkinter import*

resizeTest = Tk()
resizeTest.title('Resize Test')
resizeTest.geometry('220x100')
menubar = Menu(resizeTest)
#----------view menu
def normal():
    resizeTest.geometry('220x100')
def enlarge():
    resizeTest.geometry('500x360')

viewMenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff = 0)    
viewMenu.add_command(label="Enlarge                Alt+1", command=enlarge)
viewMenu.add_command(label="Normal                 Alt+2", command=normal)
menubar.add_cascade(label="View", menu=viewMenu)
buttons = Frame(resizeTest, bd=0, width=5, height=1, relief=GROOVE)
buttons.grid(column=0, row=1, padx=1)    
numbers=["7", "4", "1", "8", "5", "2", "9", "6", "3"]
for index in range(9):
    n=numbers[index]
    Button(buttons, bg="White", text=n,width=5,height=1, relief=GROOVE).grid(padx=2,pady=2, row=index%3,column=index/3) 
resizeTest.config(menu=menubar)
resizeTest.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got it, had to change to the pack method but cracked it in the end, Thanks for your help

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from Tkinter import *
class resizeTest:
    def __init__( self, master ):
        def normal():
            self.ma.geometry('220x100')     
        def enlarge():
            self.ma.geometry('500x360')
        self.ma = master
        self.ma.title('Resize Test')
        self.ma.geometry('220x100')
        self.f = Frame( self.ma )
        self.f.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES)
        self.enlarge = Button( self.f, text='Enlarge', height=1, width=10, padx=0, pady=1, command=enlarge)
        self.enlarge.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH,expand=YES)
        self.normal = Button( self.f, text='Normal', height=1, width=10, padx=0, pady=1, command=normal)
        self.normal.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=BOTH,expand=YES)
root = Tk()
app = resizeTest(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like this? Adding a function to create the buttons, with width and height arguments, could be called in your resize functions to set up buttons to match the window size. Not exactly bound automatically, but it works.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from Tkinter import*

resizeTest = Tk()
resizeTest.title('Resize Test')
resizeTest.geometry('220x100')
menubar = Menu(resizeTest)
#----------view menu
def normal():
    buttons.grid_forget()
    resizeTest.geometry('220x100')
    add_buttons(5, 1)
def enlarge():
    buttons.grid_forget()
    resizeTest.geometry('500x360')
    add_buttons(18, 6)

def add_buttons(w,h):
    global buttons
    buttons = Frame(resizeTest, bd=0, relief=GROOVE)
    buttons.grid(column=0, row=1, padx=1) 
    numbers=["7", "4", "1", "8", "5", "2", "9", "6", "3"]
    for index in range(9):
        n=numbers[index]
        Button(buttons, bg="White", text=n, width=w, height=h, relief=GROOVE).grid(padx=2,pady=2, row=index%3,column=index/3)   

viewMenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff = 0)    
viewMenu.add_command(label="Enlarge                Alt+1", command=enlarge)
viewMenu.add_command(label="Normal                 Alt+2", command=normal)
menubar.add_cascade(label="View", menu=viewMenu)
add_buttons(5, 1)
resizeTest.config(menu=menubar)
resizeTest.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, yes that is exactly what i was after, the enlarge and normal options now work how i would like. The only trouble now is that when you drag the corner of the window the buttons don't resize, do you know of any way i can fix this. Many thanks

Comment: on reflection I imagine that it will be complicated because the buttons need to check the size of the screen and resize accordingly, maybe if the buttons were bound to the window?? been scratching my head on this one for nearly a week now lol,The best I managed was to get my buttons to enlarge but when I clicked normal it just put small buttons on top of the big ones lol. Every time i tried to bind the buttons I got errors and it crashed

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure how to go about that. You'd need a function to change the width and height of the button, I'd imagine, but I don't know how to call that from a window being manually resized.

Comment: been trying to implement the code from this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12018540/python3-how-to-dynamically-resize-button-text-in-tkinter-ttk) but its just not working for me