# Trying to provide skinning type functionality to tkinter gui

Tags: python, tkinter, themes, skin

I want to be able to do things like use inverted colors in my GUI (e.g perhaps light green on black), and to overall increase the font size used.

I do like some of the extra functionality provided by ttk over tkinter, but it seems there is no overall hierarchy to the information. Every widget has a complete definition of its appearance / behaviour for each theme.

So it would appear that I will need to get the styles associated with each control my app uses, and change the font size, foreground and background individually for each style. Is this really the way to do it, or is there a better solution to this problem?

There was a hint at the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12018540/python3-how-to-dynamically-resize-button-text-in-tkinter-ttk?rq=1) for the size parts at least.

and right at the bottom of [this](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/ttk-style-layer.htmlhttp://) page there is mention of a 'hidden' root style in ttk. Note though that not all styles properly inherit from here *sigh*.

So here is a very little app that dynamically changes *some* font sizes. The size starts off as a negative number, and initial behaviour is strange, but once the numbers are positive, behaviour is OK.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
#from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12018540/python3-how-to-dynamically-resize-button-text-in-tkinter-ttk?rq=1
from tkinter import Tk, StringVar, font
from tkinter.ttk import Frame, Button, Label, Entry, Style

class ButtonApp(Tk):
    """Container for the buttons."""

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.createWidgets()

        # grab the current theme
        self.theme = Style()

    def createWidgets(self):
        """Make the widgets."""

        self.plusbut = Button(self, text='+font+')
        self.plusbut.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky='nsew')
        self.plusbut['command'] = self.fontup
        self.minusbut = Button(self, text='-font-')
        self.minusbut.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky='nsew')
        self.minusbut['command'] = self.fontdn
        self.alabel = Label(self, text='Label 42:')
        self.alabel.grid(column=0, row=1)
        self.blabel = Label(self, text='Label 43:')
        self.blabel.grid(column=0, row=2)
        self.sstr = StringVar()
        self.sstr.set("here is an input field")
        self.entfld = Entry(self,textvariable=self.sstr)
        self.entfld.grid(column=1, row=1)

    def fontup(self):
        self.changefont(1)

    def fontdn(self):
        self.changefont(-1)

    def changefont(self, change):
        fn=self.theme.lookup('.','font')
        df=font.nametofont(fn)
        sz=df.cget('size')
        df.configure(size=sz+change)
        newtext = "font size now %d" % (sz+change)
        self.alabel.configure(text=newtext)
        self.blabel.configure(text="actual font size is %d" % df.actual('size'))

root = ButtonApp()
root.title('playing with styles')
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I think I have solved the font size problem at least - a couple of ttk widgets (Entry, Combobox, Spinbox) use the named font TkTextFont, so this font needs to be changed as well.